# Wipe the pair of tweezers with a fiberless wipe ____ the 76 % medical antiseptic solution. (which word to use?)

Tags: word-request, phrase-request

I'm trying to translate a Russian sentence from a biotech-related technical text as closely to the original as possible. The original sentence is:

> Пинцет обрабатывают безворсовой салфеткой, **смоченной** 76 % медицинским антисептическим раствором.

My attempt:

> Wipe the pair of tweezers with a fiberless wipe ____ the 76 % medical antiseptic solution.

I'm not sure which word would be the most natural in the underscored location. Containing? Treated with? Impregnated with? Doused with? Dunked in?

The Russian original word, **смоченной**, means "moistened with".

I googled around and it looks like structures like this are used:

> Disinfect the scissors and tweezers with **an alcohol wipe** before and after use...

But that would hardly work in my case.

> Wipe the tweezers **with varnish thinner** immediately after use ...

This omits the use of the "wiping material" altogether, and would not work in my case.

---

P.S. Maybe one should flip-flop the sentence? Like this:

> Wipe the pair of tweezers with the 76 % medical antiseptic solution **applied to** a lint-free wipe.

Comment: The phrase **saturated with** would probably work, if you don't like **moistened with**.  What is the problem with "moistened"?  "... a fiberless wipe moistened with the 76% medical antiseptic solution".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo - so "moistened with" is okay? Thank you! In the meantime I reworked my translation to "*Wipe a pair of tweezers with the 76 % medical antiseptic solution using a fiberless wipe.*"

Comment: My only doubt about **moistened with** is that it gives the person latitude to decide when the wipe is moist enough, whereas **saturated with** does not. I'd be inclined to write "well moistened with" :) Don't want those tweezers to spread infection.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo How about *soaked in*?

Comment: **soaked in** is also a possibility. It's roughly synonymous with **saturated** but in a different register. *Rags soaked in oil were wrapped around sticks and used as torches.*  *The bandage was soaked in blood.*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest a different structure:

- *Disinfect the pincette with a lint free wipe moistened with 76% medical antiseptic solution.*

As for the word to choose: "**moist**" is perfectly fine in medicine. But as much as we can understand from the sentence, the wipe should be thoroughly wet and not just slightly wet, so maybe "**soaked in**" would be an even better choice.

As for the word "**pincette**" *(a small pair of pincers used in surgery)* it all depends on the type of instrument mentioned. It might be a pair of pincers, forceps (used in surgery). See [What Are the Differences between Tweezers and Forceps?](http://www.wisegeekhealth.com/what-are-the-differences-between-tweezers-and-forceps.htm) and [Pincet *(pincette)*](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/pincet) and [Tweezers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tweezers)

If you are speaking of medicine then perhaps "**forceps**" ([**thumb forceps**](https://www.wpiinc.com/productindexpages/thumb-forceps/)) or "**[pair of forceps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forceps)**" would be your best choice.

Comment: Thank you for **lint free wipe**. I used ["fiberless wipe" because Multitran said so](https://www.multitran.ru/c/M.exe?l1=1&l2=2&s=%E1%E5%E7%E2%EE%F0%F1%EE%E2%E0%FF+%F1%E0%EB%F4%E5%F2%EA%E0), but was very, very unsure whether this is the correct translation: it evokes almost no google-hits.

Comment: I'm not sure about "pincette", but too lazy to ask a separate question about that.

Comment: **moistened *in*** is not quite idiomatic. +1 for "lint-free".

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I agree. I Googled and you're right!

Answer (score 1):

I've just come across the phrase **impregnated wipe**, apparently in use in this sector. Thus the word **impregnated** might fit.

> [image]